# Sum string inside <span> </span> with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some numbers inside span in my code that I want to sum.

```
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
            weight: 0.1 lb
          </span>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
            weight: 0.5 lb
          </span>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
            weight: 0.2 lb
          </span>
           .
           .
           .
```

I want to sum 0.1 + 0.5 + ... + n= total and store the total in a variable X

Comment: What do you mean? 
The code is above. It can been calculated by class name of span. 
I don't know how to do in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using `jquery`

```js
var total = 0;
$(".product__description__property").each(function(d) {
  var value = $(this).text().replace("weight: ", "").replace(" lb", "");
  total += +value;
});
document.write("<br/>Total:"+total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
            weight: 0.1 lb
          </span>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
            weight: 0.5 lb
          </span>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
            weight: 0.2 lb
          </span>
```

You need to use `.each` to find your sum and store in a variable, use that variable to display.

Comment: How to put the variable total from the script in the data-checkout-subtotal-price

 <input class="input-radio" data-checkout-subtotal-price="$TOTAL"  />

Comment: Ok found it. 
I changed your code with: 
document.getElementById('total').textContent = total;

Comment: @ArensMyzyri This answer based on jquery so if you want to change `data` attribute using jquery you should use `$('.input-radio').data('checkout-subtotal-price', total)`;

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()` to target all the spans with `product__description__property` class and `regex` to extract the number from your string, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('product__description__property');
var total = 0;

for ( var i=0 ; i<spans.length; i++){
  var span_text = spans[i].textContent;
  var span_number =  parseFloat ( span_text.match(new RegExp("weight: (.*) lb"))[1] );

  total += span_number;
}

document.getElementById('total').textContent = total;
```

```html
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
  weight: 0.1 lb
</span>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
  weight: 0.5 lb
</span>
<span class="product__description__property order-summary__small-text">
  weight: 0.2 lb
</span>
<br>
<br>
Total : <span id='total'></span>
```

Comment: Any elegant solution other than `split` ?

Comment: Yes he can use regex instead.

Comment: I suppose its better to stay away from the position(index) of the floating value...

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/9wo6k0Lm/)

```
var total = 0;
$( ".product__description__property" ).each( function() {  

  var valueArr = $.trim( $( this ).html() ).split( " " ) ;
  console.log( valueArr );
  total += parseFloat( valueArr[ 1 ]);

} );

console.log( total );
```

Comment: I want the total of the numbers. Not the all string. 
0.1+0.5 = 0.6

Comment: I think because there's no jquery tag in question, and your answer based on jquery.

Comment: @ArensMyzyri "I want the total of the numbers. Not the all string. 0.1+0.5 = 0.6" which is what I have done. Did you checked the fiddle?